# Tap vs. mineral water for drinking

Tags: human-biology, nutrition

I was told a human should drink a small glass (0,3 liter) of mineral water per day to get the minerals. What is the rationale behind this? What is the difference between tap water and mineral water in terms of nutrition facts and effects on human health?

Values for tap water in my area:

[image]

How good are the values regarding nutrition facts?

Comment: it all depends on where you live and how your neighborhood water supply is..

Comment: You physician is the best one to answer questions about the rationale behind this recommendation.

Comment: We spent all but the last few thousand years or so of our evolutionary history exclusively drinking mineral water so it is reasonable to suspect there may be things that benefit us in naturally-occurring, mineral-laden water. If you live in the US there is also a lot of discussion about the health effects of chlorine in tap water as it may be a carcinogen and have a lot of other possible bad effects. I could also write a book about the tremendous amount of incompetency I have witnessed surrounding the management of public drinking water. I try to consume tap water in moderation.

Comment: @Kozuch I propose you change this question to discuss about necessary minerals and their role with necessary hormones in human body. The only necessary hormones are Insulin (glucose), Parathyroid hormone (calcium) and aldosterone (Na ad K). Pay attention to Calcium especially. Please, see this http://ajcn.nutrition.org/content/71/4/999.full

Answer (score 6):

The mineral content in tap water differs from area to area as well as the source. The mineral content in bottled water is regulated by the companies that manufacture them, in particular the Mg and Ca content([reference](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1495189/)).

> Death rates tend to be lower in areas with tap water containing higher
>   levels of Ca and Mg. It has been shown that deficiencies in magnesium
>   are capable of producing heart disturbances, including 215,000 fatal
>   heart attacks in the U.S. each year, and as many as 20,000,000 fatal
>   heart attacks worldwide ([reference](http://people.chem.duke.edu/~jds/cruise_chem/water/wattap.html)).

Different brands of bottled water will differ in their mineral content as well ([reference](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&ved=0CEwQFjAG&url=http://www.nuffieldfoundation.org/sites/default/files/files/FSMQ%2520Mineral%2520water%281%29.doc&ei=-AmOU5vpKpe78gX_x4LoBA&usg=AFQjCNGl0GTfR-rGSFwda4tZ_v3pkDWhyg&sig2=T1Yzth_8SbrIWebz9gMS5Q&bvm=bv.68191837,d.dGc)). The place where you stay might be lacking in a particular mineral that your body requires which is why your doctor has specified the use of a particular brand of mineral water.

Answer (score 3):

The main minerals in tap water are calcium and magnesium, which determine the hardness of water. The main minerals in mineral waters are calcium, magnesium, sodium, chloride, carbonate and sulfate. Tap water from different regions and various brands of mineral water can contain very different amounts of minerals, so it is impossible to make a general recommendation to drink more mineral water.

Mineral water high in calcium or magnesium can be a good source of calcium and magnesium for people who do not get enough calcium from foods. Foods are much better source of calcium and magnesium than water, though.

Researchers from the World Health Organization (WHO) claim that water hardness (calcium and magnesium content) has no effects on health (positive or negative).

Foods high in calcium, beneficial and harmful effects of calcium and references to claims I made:
http://www.nutrientsreview.com/minerals/calcium-ca.html

Calcium concentration in bottled and mineral waters (US, Europe):
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2488164/table/Tab2/

Comment: Agreed, if foods high in calcium and magnesium are touted as "super foods" then it is illogical to reprimand water for the same thing. its all going in the same place lol